# Kruskal Wallis test always gives nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to work on a Kruskal-Wallis test over several columns against my 'age' column in the dataframe. However, whenever I run it despite removing nas with dropna() I still get all nan values for all the groups.

```
from scipy.stats import kruskal

columns_to_test = ['benefits', 'resources', 'mhd', 'coworker_chat', 'support_options', 'remote']

kruskal_results = []

# Iterate through the columns and perform the Kruskal-Wallis test
for column in columns_to_test:
    filtered_data = df.dropna(subset=[column, 'age']) 
    group_data = [filtered_data[filtered_data[column] == group]['age'] for group in df[column].unique()]
    
    stat, p = kruskal(*group_data)
    kruskal_results.append({'Column': column, 'Statistics': stat, 'p-value': p})

for result in kruskal_results:
    print(f"Column: {result['Column']}, Statistics: {result['Statistics']}, p-value: {result['p-value']}")
```

This code includes a check to ensure that there is enough data (more than one group) to perform the Kruskal-Wallis test. If there's only one group remaining (after dropping NaN values), the test won't be performed, preventing NaN results. Why do I still get nans when I do this? Thank you for the help

Comment: maybe because on group data, there is nan result. You can check with this selection `if len(group_data) > 1:` before append to `kruskal_results`

Comment: Thank you, there are nans in `group_data` and it seems even if I add a .dropna() to the list comprehension, it still finds nan values. I'm not sure how to proceed to remove these from there

Comment: I had similar issue, after dropping NaNs everything worked, thank you. That is strange, tough, that the test just fails silently and produces NaNs instead of giving at least a warning. Maybe worth creating a SciPy issue for that.

Comment: Created an issue, we will see what happens now: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/20056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing might be due to the way you're filtering and processing your data within the loop. It's possible that there are still `NaN` values present in the `group_data` list, causing `NaN` results in the Kruskal-Wallis test. Here's a modified version of your code that should help ensure that `NaN` values are properly handled:

```
from scipy.stats import kruskal
import numpy as np

columns_to_test = ['benefits', 'resources', 'mhd', 'coworker_chat', 'support_options', 'remote']

kruskal_results = []

# Iterate through the columns and perform the Kruskal-Wallis test
for column in columns_to_test:
    # Drop rows with NaN values in both 'column' and 'age'
    filtered_data = df.dropna(subset=[column, 'age']) 
    
    # Group the 'age' values by unique values in 'column'
    groups = filtered_data[column].unique()
    group_data = [filtered_data[filtered_data[column] == group]['age'] for group in groups]
    
    # Perform the Kruskal-Wallis test only if there are more than one group
    if len(group_data) > 1:
        stat, p = kruskal(*group_data)
        kruskal_results.append({'Column': column, 'Statistics': stat, 'p-value': p})
    else:
        kruskal_results.append({'Column': column, 'Statistics': np.nan, 'p-value': np.nan})

for result in kruskal_results:
    print(f"Column: {result['Column']}, Statistics: {result['Statistics']}, p-value: {result['p-value']}")
```

In this modified code:

1. We drop rows with NaN values in both the specified column and the 'age' column using dropna.
2. We then group the 'age' values by unique values in the specified column.
3. Before performing the Kruskal-Wallis test, we check if there are more than one group left. If there's only one group, we assign NaN values to the statistics and p-value to indicate that the test couldn't be performed.

This approach should help you avoid NaN results in the Kruskal-Wallis test when there's insufficient data for the test to be valid.

Comment: Thank you! As I wrote in my comment under the question, I had a similar problem, and after .dropna() the test returned proper results.